# How to show the MAC table for interfaces on a Junos Virtual Chassis member?

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos

I'm using this command to show the MAC address table on a Juniper EX4500 series Virtual Chassis with 2 members:

```
show ethernet-switching table
```

The results show only interfaces for the Virtual Chassis master, although there are some ports connected on the VC slave. The ports have been added to the default VLAN and show up everywhere else as normal, in the config and with `show interfaces`.

How can I show the MAC table for ports on the secondary VC member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user@host> show chassis mac-addresses
MAC address information 
  Public base address   0:90:69:0:4:0
  Public count       1008
  Private base address   0:90:69:0:7:f0
  Private count       16
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I couldn't find this anywhere. It works in regular cli mode, doesn't work in edit modes naturally.